# Backbone and JSON parse

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I have a problem with backbonejs 
I need to parse a JSON string and append it on index.html file nothing too complicated
The only problem is that I don't know how to parse correctly and append each model attribute to index.html file 
if I do console.log inside the render view it prints something like `r {....}`
and if it appear that i have 2 models in it but when I try something like returning response.title in parse i get 0 models
JSON:

```
[{"color": "green", "title": "Spinach"}, {"color": "yellow", "title": "Apple"}]
```

Here is the code:

```
(function($){
  // **ListView class**: Our main app view.       

var Link = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var C = Backbone.Collection.extend({       
   model:Link,
   url:'/json',   
  parse : function(response){
        return response;  
   }      
});

var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $('body'), // attaches `this.el` to an existing element.
// `initialize()`: Automatically called upon instantiation. Where you make all types of bindings, _excluding_ UI events, such as clicks, etc.
    events:{
      'click .tag':'inside',
    },
    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render','inside'); // fixes loss of context for 'this' within methods

       this.render(); // not all views are self-rendering. This one is.
       this.model.fetch();
    },
    // `render()`: Function in charge of rendering the entire view in `this.el`. Needs to be manually called by the user.
    render: function(){                  
       console.log( this.model );   
    },  
    inside:function(e){  
    var short_by = e.currentTarget.innerText;     
    }  
  });      
   var coll = new C;
  // **listView instance**: Instantiate main app view.
  var listView = new ListView({model:coll});
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1.) The collection contains a url to '/json', which should redirect to a url containing the json you are providing. is that a real working url?

2.) You have overriden the parse method returning the response "as is". why?

3.) You are calling the model "fetch", but the model does not have a url defined, you need to call the collection's fetch, and define a url in the collection.

4.) The call is asynchronous, you should apply a listener to the collection "sync"'s event, then call render: `this.listenTo(this.collection, "sync", this.render");` then call the collection "fetch" method.

5.) Then you can do whatever to render the collection by calling the .each() method, or toJSON() to get raw json data from the collection, or use the _.template("markup..", collection.toJSON()) function.

Comment: 1.Yes the url is working and returning a JSON in this case the example I posted 2.if I try to return response.title in console.log appear 0 models

Comment: Make sure you are calling fetch on the collection, and NOT on the model.

You should fetch the collection - and listen to the sync event when the collection arrives, then you can call render. with the toJSON() method.